# Forma de optimizar un switch en JS

Tags: javascript

Mi problema con el `switch` es que tengo 150 casos y tarda 1.5s en resolverlo (medido con `Date.now()`), quería saber si habría alguna forma de optimizar un switch de este tipo en el cual no se repite ninguna instrucción.

No pondré todos para evitar el flood, pero son alrededor de 150 casos.
Uso `JavaScript` para no derrochar recursos con `PHP`.

**switch.js**

```
switch(modelo)
{
    case 400:modelo='Landstalker';
    case 401:modelo='Bravura';
    case 402:modelo='Buffalo';
    case 403:modelo='Linerunner';
    case 404:modelo='Perennial';
    case 405:modelo='Sentinel';
    case 409:modelo='Stretch';
    case 410:modelo='Manana';
    case 411:modelo='Ifernus';
    case 412:modelo='Voodoo';
    case 413:modelo='Pony';
    case 414:modelo='Mule';
    case 415:modelo='Cheetah';
    case 418:modelo='Moonbeam';
    case 419:modelo='Esperanto';
    case 420:modelo='Taxi';
    case 421:modelo='Washington';
    case 422:modelo='Bobcat';
    case 423:modelo='Mr. Whoopee';
    case 502:modelo='Hotring Racer';
    case 503:modelo='Hotring Racer';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para un `switch( )` tan simple, un simple objeto te sirve, y te ahorrarás tanto código y *tan feo*:

```
const MODELO = {
  400: 'Landstalker',
  401: 'Bravura',
  ...
};
```

Basta con reemplazar tu `switch( )` con una simple asignación:

```
modelo = MODELO[modelo];
```

Como se indica en los comentarios, lo correcto sería preveer el caso en el que **no se encuentre** el valor buscado. Si la clave no existe, `MODELO[modelo]` devolverá `undefined`. Un simple `if( )` lo soluciona:

```
modelo = MODELO[modelo];
if( modelo === undefined ) modelo = 'VALOR_POR_DEFECTO';
```

Usando el `if( )` podemos usar cualquier valor dentro del objeto (excepto `undefined`): `false`, `null`, ... Esto nos proporciona una gran funcionalidad, pudiendo usarse en multitud de situaciones.

Comment: Excelente, no hay mejor forma de evitar un largo `switch`, y si hay nuevas opciones sólo se agregan al objeto y listo. Aunque hay que evitar valores erróneos, poniendo un valor por defecto, por ejemplo: `0: 'Valor por defecto'` y hacer la asignación mediante un ternario: `modelo = (MODELO[modelo] || MODELO[0]);`. Para más detalles ver: [_Replacing switch statements with Object literals_](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals)

Comment: Cierto, no he previsto eso. Edito :-)